# How to fix Airflow logging?

Tags: airflow

I have S3 remote logging enabled, Airflow is installed on an EC2. My dags are running however, they don't always create a log and then fails. The error is as follows:

```
*** Falling back to local log

*** Log file does not exist: /home/ec2-user/airflow/logs/REMOVED/REMOVED/2022-03-07T07:00:00+00:00/2.log

*** Fetching from: http://ip-10-105-32-92.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8793/log/REMOVED/REMOVED/2022-03-07T07:00:00+00:00/2.log

*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. Client error '404 NOT FOUND' for url 'http://ip-10-105-32-92.eu-west-1.compute.internal:8793/log/REMOVED/REMOVED/2022-03-07T07:00:00+00:00/2.log'
For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/404
```

After a few attempts (3-5), it eventually does end up working.

I have even disabled the remote logging in an attempt to debug, and it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Apache Airflow version: 2.2.4

We use a describe stacks API call to get the latest ECS Task Definition, and I've noticed we have lots of these errors:

> An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the DescribeStacks operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded